# What is the Get URL to fetch TEAM roster or user profile information?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Can someone please share the postman to fetch TEAM roster or user profile information. I am referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json

Comment: does this help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule

Comment: the various other comments and answers are referring to the "time off" roster - is that what you're looking for? It sounds from the original question like you're wanting the "team" roster itself - i.e. who is in the team? If so, the article you've linked to does provide that information, in terms of endpoint ([serviceUrl] + "/v3/conversations/{teamId}/members/" ). What else do you need? Guidance on authentication perhaps? Have you tried this out yet?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I have updated the question, I need the exact URL to fetch TEAM roaster, i need to extract userId of the all the users

Comment: I'm too short on space here, will try put it into an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Url you need is this: `[serviceUrl] + "/v3/conversations/{teamId}/members/"`

and it is based on two variables: the "teamId" is obviously different per team. However, the first part of the address (called the ServiceUrl) can *also* vary between teams, based on where they might be hosted, and you need both.

It sounds like, from the link you sent, that you already have a bot? If so, your bot can retrieve both of these required parameters. One way is that, whenever a user sends a message to the bot, to get the ServiceUrl and TeamId that are sent in the incoming "activity" object that. However, if you want it even earlier than this (i.e. before a user even sends a message to the bot), have a look at the conversationUpdate event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition) which will fire right when the bot is first added to the conversation.

Does that help?

Comment: It's important to note, if you're NOT using a bot, then none of this will apply - you won't be able to get the ServiceUrl, and you also won't be able to authenticate to it, because it requires the AppId and AppPassword for the bot, that's added to the Team. So if you *don't* have a bot, let us know that please. (it seemed like you did from the link you posted)

Comment: I have the bot, however I need the list of userID who never communicated with the bot.  i have opened new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550732/how-to-query-for-the-list-of-members-and-their-basic-profiles-including-teams-u

Comment: gives error {
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}

Comment: I not sure that permission will work actually - that's for an app calling the Graph, this is for a call to the Bot Framework, I think. It's certainly worth a try, but @RDX, I'm not sure how to authenticate this exactly in Postman - it might be worth just testing this directly in your bot. You can easily debug locally using ngrok, and make a call to the endpoint when you send yourself a message, to test this.

Comment: @RDX, I see from your most recent question that you've gotten past this point, and that you've used the URL I suggested in this answer. As a result, please mark this as the correct answer, so future readers can see it was correct. Thanks

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thankyou so much!  It worked fine till yesterday but today it is giving 403, code BotNotInConversationRoster , message The bot is not part of the conversation roster. Do you have any idea why it happened

Comment: Yeah, I saw your other question on the site and I put an answer in that question, please check it out.