# How to query for the list of members and their basic profiles, including Teams user IDs?

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there an end-to-end sample provided to query for the list of members and their basic profiles, including Teams user IDs and Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)?

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json and microsoft graph Postman collection, however it seems too complex for me to understand.

I need to fetch all the userId under for my MS Team

Comment: So far I know there is no such a way where you can get all together. You have to get it partially by each API calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json) you are following is indeed used to get the information you need, including Teams user IDs and Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

I'm not sure where you don't quite understand. But it's strongly suggested to firstly learn about [Bot Framework Rest API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

You should pay attention to how to get the [Base URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#base-uri) (`serviceUrl`). After that, you could issue a GET request on `/conversations/{teamId}/members/`, using the value of as the endpoint: `serviceUrl`.

Like this:

```
GET https://{serviceUrl}/v3/conversations/{teamId}/members/
Authorization: Bearer {access token}
Content-Type: application/json
```

For details about how to obtain an access token for your bot, see [Authenticate requests from your bot to the Bot Connector service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-to-connector).

Now you have the request endpoint and headers. You could test the Rest API in Postman.

Comment: I did tried it using PostMan, but it gives me 401. {
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}

Comment: @RDX 401 means you haven't provided a correct access token. Can you confirm it?

Comment: I use the same token for other API's like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams and it responds fine.

Comment: scopes-> "scp": "Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All profile openid email",

Comment: This is the URL -> https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/conversations/{{TeamId}}/members/

Comment: @RDX You are using a wrong token which is for Microsoft Graph resources. You need to get an access token for bot by following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-1-request-an-access-token-from-the-azure-ad-v2-account-login-service.

Comment: I got team ID from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams which looks something like this 1a6a3750-bbad-XXXX-a002-bb65cee71067. But in example the teamID is something like 19:ja0cu120i1jod12j@skype.net

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Bad format of conversation ID"
    }
}

Comment: I extracted the id from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{{TeamId}}/channels and used that , it worked!

Comment: @RDX Glad to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get teams user details is by [fetching roster details](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members).

You can also use Graph API for getting [members of a team/group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). But this API provides basic details of user. like

```
[
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
        "id": "xxxxxxx-95ea-xxxxxxxxx",
        "businessPhones": [
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        "displayName": "Vivek",
        "givenName": "Vivek",
        "jobTitle": "xxxxxxxx",
        "mail": "xxxxxxxx@microsoft.com",
        "mobilePhone": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "officeLocation": "LINCOLN xxxxxxxxx",
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": "Shah",
        "userPrincipalName": "xxxxxxxx@microsoft.com"
    },
]
```

Comment: It will not provide team user ID's

Answer (score 0):

Below are the commands I used to fetch Team user IDs

1. Step 1: Request an access token from the Azure AD v2 account login
   service
2. Step 2: Obtain TenantID
3. Step 3: Get User Access Token
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
4. Step 4: Call My Joined Team, get ID
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams
5. Step 5: Findchannels of a team
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{{TeamId}}/channels
6. Step 6:
   Find all the user profile using following
   https://{{serviceUrl}}/v3/conversations/{{channelid}}/members/